# MySQL count only new records

Tags: mysql, sql, select, count

How to write a MySQL query to achieve this task?

**Table:** writers

```
w_id    w_name
---------------
  1     Michael
  2     Samantha
  3     John
---------------
```

**Table:** articles

```
a_id   w_id   timestamp   a_name
----------------------------------------
  1      1        1       PHP programming
  2      3        3       Other programming languages
  3      3        5       Another article
  4      2       15       Web design
  5      1       20       MySQL
----------------------------------------
```

Need to **COUNT** only those **writers** who published their **first article** not earlier than **5**.
 *(only writers who published at least one article can be counted)*

In this example the result would be: **1** *(one writer - Samantha)*

SQL code can be tested [in this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0e90f)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a double SELECT.

First you fetch `w_id`, together with timestamp of first article:

```
SELECT w_id, MIN(timestamp) as publish FROM articles GROUP BY w_id
```

Then you request that `publish` is not earlier than 5:

```
SELECT w_id, MIN(timestamp) as publish
    FROM articles
    GROUP BY w_id
    HAVING publish >= 5;
```

Then you join that "table" with `writers` to get the name, if you want.

But if you only want the count, you do not need the `writers` table at all:

```
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS answer FROM
    ( SELECT w_id, MIN(timestamp) AS publish
        FROM articles
        GROUP BY w_id
        HAVING publish >= 5
) AS counter;
```

Test: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0e90f/30/0

Answer (score 2):

```
select 
  w_name
from writers w
join articles a on w.w_id = a.w_id
group by w.w_id,w.w_name
having min(timestamp)>=5
```

with fiddle .. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0e90f/11/0

or to count ..

```
select 
 count(w_name)
from writers w
join articles a on w.w_id = a.w_id
group by w.w_id,w.w_name
having min(timestamp)>=5
```

with fiddle .. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0e90f/27/0

Answer (score 2):

You need to have a subquery to get the writer's minimum `timestamp`.The result will then be counted sinceyou cannot aggregate a column that is already aggregated (*eg. COUNT(MIN(columnName))*)

```
SELECT COUNT(*) totalWriters
FROM
(
  SELECT  a.w_id, MIN(b.`timestamp`)
  FROM    writers a
          INNER JOIN articles b
            ON a.w_id = b.w_id
  GROUP BY a.w_id
  HAVING MIN(b.`timestamp`) >= 5
) a
```

## [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0e90f/24)

Answer (score 2):

It's easy, here is the query:

```
SELECT count(DISTINCT w_id)
FROM articles
WHERE TIMESTAMP>=5 
AND w_id NOT IN (SELECT w_id FROM articles WHERE TIMESTAMP<5);
```

See [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/19df9/6)

Answer (score 1):

An easy solution:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT w_id)
FROM writers
WHERE w_id NOT IN
(SELECT w_id from articles
 WHERE timestamp <=5)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select count(*)
from (
    select w_id, min(`timestamp`) as `timestamp`
    from articles
    group by w_id
) s
where `timestamp` >= 5
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select count(1) from (
     select w.w_id, count(a.timestamp) cnt from writers w
     inner join articles a on a.w_id = w.w_id
     group by w.w_id
  ) t
inner join articles art on art.w_id = t.w_id
where t.cnt = 1 and art.timestamp > 5
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, i have just tested..

```
select*   from ( select tblw.w_id, count(tblart.timestamp) count from writers tblw  inner join articles tblart on tblart.w_id = tblw.w_id   group by tblw.w_id ) temp inner join articles art on art.w_id = temp .w_id where temp .count = 1 and art.timestamp > 5
```